# auto complete for angular js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to implement the auto suggest box for a input text field in angular js .
I used the reference from the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/light/

what i have tried is  in front end.

```
<input type="text" auto-complete ui-items="suggestionPhrase"  id="ingredients" ng-model="searchString" ng-change="callSuggestion()" ng-enter="getRecipesTracknPlan()" placeholder="Type of ingredients / recipe">
```

and the js file is

```
var app = angular.module('tracknplanApp', ['checklist-model','ui.bootstrap','ui.utils']);`enter code here`app.config(['$locationProvider',
function ($locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); }]);

app.controller('tracknplanctrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, searchStringSelected, $modal, $filter) {
console.log("Running Track n plan controller.");
/*angular.element('#recipeNVariantTabs').removeClass('hidden-xs');
angular.element('#recipeNVariantTabs').removeClass('hidden-sm');*/
$scope.showVariants = false;
var trackNPlanDate = new Date();
var foodSearchDate = new Date();
var activitySearchDate = new Date();
$scope.callSuggestion= function(){

     if ($scope.searchString){
       console.log("inside initializeFoodSuggestion",$scope.searchString);
       angular.element.ajax({
                url: "http://dev2.slim.in:8983/solr/food/suggest",
                data: {
                    "q": $scope.searchString,
                    "wt": "json",
                    "spellcheck": "true",
                    "spellcheck.build": "true"
                 },
                traditional: true,
                cache: true,
                async: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (data) {
                    //and when we get the query back we
                    //stick the results in the scope
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.suggestionPhrase = data.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion;
                        console.log("suggestion from solr is  ",$scope.suggestionPhrase)
                    });
                },
                jsonp: 'json.wrf'
            });

}}

app.directive('autoComplete', function() {
 return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source: $scope.suggestionPhrase,
            select: function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                  iElement.trigger('input');
                }, 0);
            }
        });
};});
```

I am not sure where my code goes wrong please point out the error in this.

Comment: can you prepare fiddle for your code?

Comment: sorry i am not sure how to do it please find the error from above code it self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't found the directive working so i got the jquery autocomplete

```
 $("#ingredients").autocomplete({
            source:function(request, response) { 
            angular.element.ajax({
                url: "http://dev2.slim.in:8983/solr/food/suggest",
                data: {
                    "q": $scope.searchString,
                    "wt": "json",
                    "spellcheck": "true",
                    "spellcheck.build": "true"



                },
                traditional: true,
                cache: true,
                async: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (data) {
                    //and when we get the query back we
                    //stick the results in the scope
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.suggestionPhrase = data.spellcheck.suggestions[1].suggestion;
                          console.log("before suggestprint")


                        console.log("suggestion from solr is  ",$scope.suggestionPhrase)
                                response($scope.suggestionPhrase);               

                    });
                },
                jsonp: 'json.wrf'
            });} });
```